# How to change state into onFinish in ant design in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, antd, react-forms

Here, i am trying to change my state when form validation is complete. But i dont know why my state is not changing in onFinish function. My code:-

```
import { Form, Input, Button, Result } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { selectViewResult, setViewDate, setViewResult } from "../../features/userSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector  } from "react-redux";
const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 8,
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 16,
  },
};

const validateMessages = {
  required: "${label} is required!",
  types: {
    email: "${label} is not a valid email",
    number: "${label} is not a valid number",
  },
};





const Formm = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onFinish=(value) =>{
    console.log(value);
    dispatch(setViewDate(true));
 dispatch(setViewResult(true));
  
  console.log(success)
    
   
 
    
    
    
}

const success= useSelector(selectViewResult);
  return (
      <>
      {
        !success ? <>
        <h1>Details About You</h1><Form style={{marginRight:"500px"}} {...layout} onFinish={onFinish}  validateMessages={validateMessages} >
      <Form.Item 
      name={['user', 'name']}
      label="Name"
      rules={
          [
              {
                  required:true,
              }
          ]
      }>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item 

      label="Email"
      name={['user', 'email']}
      rules={
          [
              {
                  type:'email',
                  required:true,
              },
          ]
      }>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item 
      name={['user', 'number']}
      label="Number"
      rules={
          [
              {
                 
                  required:true,
              },
          ]
      }>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item 
      name={['user', 'reason']}
      label="Reason Behind Appointment">
        <Input.TextArea />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ ...layout.wrapperCol, offset: 8 }}>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onChange={hh}>Submit</Button>
      </Form.Item>
      
    </Form> </>:<Result
     title="Great, Appoinment Has Been Set. See You soon."
     extra={<Button type='primary'>Done</Button>}
     />

    }
      
    
      
    </>
    
  );
  
}

export default Formm;
```

I have tried many ways to solve this but eventually i have failed. I tried onChange, onClick etc for changing my state. but nothing changing. every time **success variable** is showing false.

Comment: You are only logging it from the `onFinish` which can only be called when the `Form` is visible, which only shows when `success` is `false`. Try logging the `success` right after `const success= useSelector(selectViewResult);`

Comment: your code will throw error, since success is not defined.. If you are trying to log it in onFinish it will always be false, since when success is false then only you can trigger onFinish ...If it is true then it shows Result component.....
To log success as true , you have to console it outside onFinish next to useSelector declaration

Comment: Is you question, since state change triggered in before line to true dispatch(setViewResult(true))... it should show success as true in next line ?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. My problem has been solved. Wish you both goodness from my heart.